# Static Library and deployment target issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6, static-libraries, linker-errors

I am working on iphone app with deployment target 5.1.1 and now i am adding google ios sdk in my project. I am not giving this functionality to user who has iOS 5.1.1 in device.

But google iOS Sdk needs to set `Other Linker flag (-ObjC)` in build setting and it creates problem in iOS 5.1.1.

is there any way to set Other Linker flag conditionally? i need to give support for iOS 5.1.1.

I tried below steps but not able to run app in iOS 5.1.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end compiler will generate single binary. Whether you provide certain feature in iOS 5.1.1  or not does not matter to compiler. So if you need to set deployment target to iOS 5.1.1  then all the static libraries you link must also support that particular deployment target.

More details on [ObjC flag](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html)